JTabbedPane : Add component at custom location
In a Swing application with JTabbedPane navigation style the user can select the part of application nicely. Now I want to add something like a Help or Configuration tab. But rather than just another tab, this one shall be displayed on the very right of the tabs.
The red area in this picture should give you an idea what I have in mind:

While I can try to modify how the tab is displayed via setTabComponent I have no clue how to ensure it is displayed on the right (or end if talking about vertical alignment).
How would that be possible?

Seems like the layout of tabs is handled by the BasicTabbedPaneUI (which is unfortunate for portable customizations in general). In case you are looking for portability and don't want to roll your own tabbed pane header and you are willing to use a different L&F, then maybe you can try with FlatLaf trailingComponent property. I didn't try it though, sorry, just a suggestion.

Long ago, it was standard for user interfaces with menu bars to place a Help menu at the far right end of the menu bar. However, subsequent usability studies found that users often didn’t notice the Help menu when it was all the way on the end. The practice fell out of favor, and in fact the setHelpMenu method of JMenuBar was never implemented. Just making your Help or Configuration tab the last tab, without any special placement, is probably a good design.

While I'd agree with such studies just look how today's browsers look like. But now I am thinking to replace the tabbedpane with a CardLayout and either a MenuBar or a custom button panel.
